# Is this case of paint detaching a sign of water damage?

Tags: water-damage

Living in and administrating a condo building, I recently noticed some of the paint had started detaching from the ceiling, nearby the front entrance. See pictures below.

I fear it might be a sign of water leaking in and could be hiding more water damage. I haven't seen water dripping from there yet.

I contacted a few companies, but they asked for CAD 1000$ just to come and give an estimate.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $1,000 CAD for an estimate!?!?!   That's outrageous.  Since it's already de-laminating, you may as well go ahead and peal off as much as possible and inspect for moisture damage.   It's amazing how much water can be held by paint.   You're going to have to get into it anyway for repairs so go for it.   And yes, it does look like water damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are literally water stains all over the wall next to the damaged paint.  It is not necessary to see it "dripping" when there's already this much damage.  The answer is yes, you have a leak and obvious water damage.

[image: Water stains highlighted]

Comment: Pretty much what I feared. Any way I can avoid the steep price for an estimate? I'm assuming I will have to go with a professional for repairs.

Comment: The best way to avoid the steep estimate is to never do business with those "few companies" who are trying to take advantage of you and instead hire some honest maintenance workers or a contractor.  Most roofing contractors would give you a free exterior inspection and an opinion.  Some might be able to recommend a competent contractor for the ceiling repair.

Comment: If Canadian laws are anything like American laws, you will most likely need licensed contractors to do the work on a multi-unit dwelling. You're allowed (in the US) to work on your own residence and put your own life at risk, but not on a residence where other families live. Just keep calling different contractors in town until you find the ones who do an estimate for free. They'll also be willing to supply a list of references to other work they've done so you can talk to others about their quality

Answer (score 1):

It looks somewhat like a moisture problem but it's difficult to tell from your photos.  You might want to procure a moisture content meter and measure your wallboard material and any wood for excess moisture content.